# Why/How is it possible to copy 32 bit librarys form Ubuntu to an ARM machine?

Tags: 32-bit, shared-library, arm, raspberrypi

This is not too ubuntu specific but kind of.

I wanted to setup a dedicated game server for Don't Starve together which is only avaiable in 32 bit. I installed it on ubuntu and it worked perfectly then I wanted to run it on my bananapi which has an ARM processor. I started coping all the librarys from my ubuntu computer to my arm machine and the server works.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Installing 32bit libs works on a 64bit processor because 64bit is a superset of 32bit CPU instructions. However **ARM CPUs use a different instruction set**. Even if you installed the libraries, you can't use them without also emulating a 32bit x86 CPU for everything to run through.

You *can* [do that with Qemu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/QemuEmulator) (or another virtualisation option that supports ARM hosts), essentially running a second x86 version of Ubuntu in the background but it's obviously going to be quite slow. I woulnd't want to play a demanding game.

There are also [commercial options](http://eltechs.com/product/exagear-desktop/) in the space but they cost as much as another ARM board.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have custom paths for your [qemu-user](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation) libarys?